# how to create a URL validation for these requirements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

hi i have a jquery validation method for URL validation ,

currently i use a validation rule like this

```
 var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
 var urltest=urlregex.test(url);
```

this validates

1 . `http://abcd`  to true .

2 . `http://abcd.com`  to true .

3 . `http://www.abcd`  to true .

4 . `http://www.abcd.com`  to true .

i want to be true only the 4 th URL .

i want a validation that needs

`www` with `http:// (or like https:// , ftp://)` and to end with `.com (or like .org , .lk)`

only URL's like this should validate true

```
http://www.abcd.com
http://www.efgh.lk
```

please help . thanks in advance ........................

Comment: so something like `http://google.com` should be not valid?

Comment: @Vytautas according to my QA team , YES .. :'(

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya this is somewhat wrong... You should notice them, because final users may not understand why `http://google.com` does not validate

Comment: that's too bad. a lot of web pages does not work with `www.` maybe you should explain that to your QA team..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/www\.[-0-9a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$
```

**Update**
Regex object initialization + unlimited number of subdomains + upto 4 characters in root domain:

```
var urlregex = new RegExp(/^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/www\.([-0-9a-zA-Z]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/);
```

Comment: `^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/www.[-0-9a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$` would be more efficient

Comment: in case we want unlimited number of subdomains:
`^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/www\.([-0-9a-zA-Z]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$`

Comment: @yuvin thank you very much for your answer. but this validates url's like www.kkk k klllllllllll.com to true , witch have spaces in url . please help to validate url's with out spaces .

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya please make sure you use updated answer (with dots escaped like this: `\.`) Otherwise `.` means 'any symbol'.

Comment: i used this one ^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/www\.([-0-9a-zA-Z]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Try building RegExp object using slashes instead of quotes:
`var urlregex = new RegExp(/^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/www\.([-0-9a-zA-Z]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/);`

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya, does it work for you? If it does would you mind accepting this answer please? If not then just let me know and I'll be glad assisting you with that regex. Thanks!

Comment: i think this works corrrectly var urlregex = new RegExp(/^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/www\.([-0-9a-zA-Z]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/);